# How to sort list after 3 criteria and delete all duplicate rows but the last one?

Tags: excel, vba

So after some helpful input I came up with this piece of code.
This will sort the data after the criteria.

Now is it possible to delete all but the last row with the same `Name` and  same `Release`?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sortieren()
'
' Sortieren Makro
'
' Tastenkombination: Strg+q
'
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ag-grid").ListObjects("Tabelle1").Sort.SortFields. _
        Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ag-grid").ListObjects("Tabelle1").Sort.SortFields. _
        Add Key:=Range("Tabelle1[Name]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ag-grid").ListObjects("Tabelle1").Sort.SortFields. _
        Add Key:=Range("Tabelle1[Release]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ag-grid").ListObjects("Tabelle1").Sort.SortFields. _
        Add Key:=Range("Tabelle1[Gestartet]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ag-grid").ListObjects("Tabelle1").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

I tried to delete the columns with this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Löschen()
'
' Löschen Makro
'
' Tastenkombination: Strg+w
'
    ActiveSheet.Range("Tabelle1[#Alle]").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(3, 12), _
        Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

but it just deleted all but the first one. I want exactly the opposite.

I want to delete these rows:
[image: I want to delete these columns]

Ps: sorry for the first draft!

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: To start, use the Macro Recoder and examine the resulting code

Comment: @ganzo Could you provide a screenshot (after filtering) and mark the cells that should be cleared? That would make it easier to understand.

Comment: I hope the screenshot helps

Comment: Since the rows are no complete duplicates, you probably cannot use the `.RemoveDuplicates` method. The question is how do you decide which of the duplicates should be kept and which should be removed? Is it aways the last one of the duplicates that shoud be kept and every duplicate before that is removed? We need a very precise rule here otherwise your result will be randomly.

Comment: So if i have the same "Name" AND same "Release", for example Parken and R-19-02, I want to delete all but the last column.

Comment: *"all but the last column."* did you accidentally mix up columns with rows and actually mean *"all but the last row"*? To clarify a row is how you marked in yellow and a column is for example "Name" (and downwards). That would explain why I don't understand your question.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right.

Comment: @GanZo Then see my anwer below.

Answer (score 0):

Since the [Range.RemoveDuplicates method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.removeduplicates) always keeps the first row and removes the duplicates below, you must sort your column `Gestartet` *descending* instead of *ascending*.

So the following should work in combination with `.RemoveDuplicates`

```
Sub Sortieren()
'
' Sortieren Makro
'
' Tastenkombination: Strg+q
'
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ag-grid").ListObjects("Tabelle1").Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Tabelle1[Name]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Tabelle1[Release]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Tabelle1[Gestartet]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```